# ¿como puedo mostrar los registros de una base de datos mysql en java?

Tags: mysql, jsp, java-ee, servlets

soy nuevo utilizando javaweb lo que sucede es que hice un proyecto que es capaz de mostrar los registros de una base de datos sql,en lo que quisiera que me ayudaran es como puedo hacerlo utilizando servlets.

Esta es el codigo para para mostrar los registros:

```
<%-- 
    Document   : pacientes
    Created on : 27/08/2020, 11:01:11 AM
    Author     : mateo
--%>

<%@page import="javax.naming.spi.DirStateFactory.Result"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="estilos/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Pacientes</title>
    </head>
    <body>
   <%
   String USERNAME = "root";
     String PASSWORD= "";
     String HOST ="localhost";
     String PORT = "3306";
     String DATABASE= "hospital";
     String CLASSNAME = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
     String URL = "jdbc:mysql://"+HOST+":"+PORT+"/"+DATABASE;
     Connection con;
     Class.forName(CLASSNAME);
     con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL,USERNAME,PASSWORD);
     //listar datos de la tabla pacientes
     PreparedStatement ps;
     ResultSet rs;
     
     ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from pacientes");
     rs = ps.executeQuery();
     //table
   %>
   <div class="container">
       <h1>Lista de pacientes</h1> 
       <hr>
       <table class="table table-bordered">
          
           <% if(rs.first()){%>
             <% rs.beforeFirst(); %>
           <tr>
               <th class="text-center">ID</th>
               <th >NOMBRE </th>
               <th class="text-center">FECHA</th>
          
               <th class="text-center">IDENTIFICACION</th>
               <th class="text-center">TIPO DE IDENTIFICACION</th>
               <th class="text-center">EPS</th>
               <th class="text-center">HISTORIA CLINICA</th>
               <th class="text-center">ACCIONES</th>
           </tr>
           
           <%while(rs.next()){ %>
           <tr>
               
               <td class="text-center"><%=rs.getInt("id") %></td>
               <td class="text-center"><%=rs.getString("nombre") %></td>
               <td class="text-center"> <%=rs.getDate("fecha") %></td>
               <td class="text-center"><%=rs.getString("identificacion") %></td>
               <td class="text-center"><%=rs.getString("tidentificacion") %></td>
               <td class="text-center"><%=rs.getString("eps") %></td>
               <td class="text-center"><%=rs.getObject("historia") %></td>
               <td class="text-center">
                   <a class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Editar</a>
                   <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Eliminar</a>
               </td>
               
           </tr>
           <% } %>
          <% }else{ %>
          <h1>No hay pacientes registrados</h1>
          <% }%>
       </table>
   </div>    
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Para explicarme mejor se que existe el modelo vista controlador,la idea es dejarle la parte de logica a java,por eso la idea de lo que necesito hacer es como puedo por ejemplo utilizar una clase conexion para realizar la conexion a la base datos otra clase para las consultas a la base de datos y crear otro paquete para los servlets, entonces aca dejo como lo estoy intentando hacer:

Este es el codigo del paquete de conexion:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package Conexion;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

/**
 *
 * @author mateo
 */
public class Conexion {
    private String USERNAME = "root";
    private String PASSWORD= "";
    private String HOST ="localhost";
    private String PORT = "3306";
    private String DATABASE= "hospital";
    private String CLASSNAME = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private String URL = "jdbc:mysql://"+HOST+":"+PORT+"/"+DATABASE;
    private Connection con;
    
    public Conexion() {
        try {
            Class.forName(CLASSNAME);
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME,PASSWORD);
            
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("Error" + e);
        }
    
    }
   public  Connection getConexion(){
   return con;
   }
  
}
```

Despues de esto he estado intentando crear otra clase para las consultas y que en esta pueda mostrar los registros de la base de datos pero no se como lo puedo hacer, en resumen como podria hacer para crear la clase  consultas que hereda de conexion para mostrar los registros de la base de datos y con un servlet mostrar la base.

Muchas gracias de ante mano.

Comment: Cuál es el error?

Comment: En si no hay error,solo que no se como mostrar los registros desde una clase de java

Comment: lo hice en el jsp con parametrer, le dije select * from pacietes y asi obtuve la tabla mi pregunta es como puedo hacerlo pero desde una clase java y despue s utilizar un servlet para mostrar los registros